# Java and Arrays - Insertion sort in ascending order

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

So I need to read in a txt file with the values...

```
31 70 5 71 140 187 162 98 153 8 109 103 145 157 27 23 136 54 19 168 114 25 139 129 94
```

Here is my code right now, and I was able to use the insertion sort algorithm to sort the values into descending order. However, I also want to know how I would change my insertion sort method to sort the values into ascending order.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab3
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    if (args.length < 1)
    {
        System.out.println( "Fatal Error. Enter a filename on the command line!\n");

        System.exit(0);
    }

    int[] arr = new int[30];  
    int cnt=0;

    Scanner infile = new Scanner( new FileReader(args[0]) );
    while ( infile.hasNextInt() )
    {
        insertInOrder( arr, cnt, infile.nextInt() );
        ++cnt;  // INCR COUNT AFTER EVERY INSERTION
        printArray( arr, cnt ); // THEN PRINT ARRAY AFTER EVERY INSERTION
    }
    infile.close();

} // END main

// ======================================================================
//                  M    E   T    H    O    D   S
// ======================================================================


// YOU MUST FILL IN THIS METHOD
static void insertInOrder( int[] arr, int count, int newVal )
{
    arr[count] = newVal; //This appends the number
        for( count = 1; count<arr.length; count++)
        {
            int leftVal = count;
            newVal = arr[count];

                while((leftVal > 0) && (arr[leftVal-1]<newVal))
                {
                        arr[leftVal] = arr[leftVal-1];
                        leftVal--;
                }
                arr[leftVal] = newVal;
        }
}

// USE THIS METHOD AS GIVEN: DO NOT CHANGE
private static void printArray( int[] array, int count )
{
    for( int i=0 ; i<count ;++i )
        System.out.printf("%-4d",array[i] );  // "%-4d" means print arr[i] in 4 spaces left justified
        System.out.println();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void insertInOrder( int[] arr, int count, int newVal )
{
    arr[count] = newVal; //This appends the number
        for( count = 1; count<arr.length; count++)
```

Here you are mixing to different variables called count. One is the input parameter and the other is the variable local to for loop. Change your for loop to:

```
for( int i = 1; i<count; i++) // you need to loop only till the newest index just added.
```

As for converting from descending to ascending, then provided your descending algorithm works, you just need to change your comparison operator:

```
while((leftVal > 0) && (arr[leftVal-1]>newVal))
                                      ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the values in a NavigableSet like this

```
//for descending sort
   NavigableSet<Integer> descSet = new TreeSet<Integer>().descendingSet();
//for asc sort
      NavigableSet<Integer> ascSet = new TreeSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
List unsortedList = Arrays.asList(<<Your ARRAY>>);
Collections.sort(unsortedList, Collections.reverseOrder());
```